# Jupyter Notebook "hidecode" tag not working?

Tags: jupyter

I am trying to use the `hidecode` tag as shown [here](https://jupyter.org/jupyter-book/features/hiding.html), but for some reason, it's not working on my local Jupyter Notebook server. The code remains visible, and no button on the right of the cell is displayed. I even downloaded the [same notebook](https://jupyter.org/jupyter-book/content/features/hiding.ipynb) used in the page above, no dice.

I am running `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS`, `Jupyter Notebook Server 5.2.2`, `Python 3.6.7`, and `IPython 5.5.0`. The command I ran to start the server is `sudo jupyter notebook --allow-root`.

If you need any more info, please let me know. I appreciate any help I can get in figuring this out.

Comment: That `hidecode` tag works when you create a [jupyter-book](https://jupyter.org/jupyter-book/intro.html) only.

Comment: @TheBear44 From my understanding a jupyter "book" is just a set of HTML pages and it's not interactive (you can't edit or run code interactively). What if I want to hide some cell input or output in my jupyter notebook ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the code, the output or the prompt of your cells you can install the **hide_code** extension:

https://pypi.org/project/hide_code/0.2.0/

1. Stop jupyter
2. Run these commands

---

```
pip install hide_code

jupyter nbextension install --py hide_code

jupyter nbextension enable --py hide_code

jupyter serverextension enable --py hide_code
```

NOTE: I run the first two commands as **root** and the last two with the same user used to launch jupyter.

3. Restart jupyter

I found this extension very useful because I needed to print the notebook to a pdf file and all the tools like nbpublish, nbconvert was failing. In this way I can print the notebook directly from the "print" feature of the browser.